# How can I add a non-CMake library to a CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I use CMake for my project and would like to add a dependency to it in the form of a library that does not use cmake. I want to make sure that the library can be used later with the target_link_libraries command. That is, in order for cmake to know which file to link, to know which directory is include for the library.

For example, some libraries use `autotools` to build and install applications and the build process involves the following set of commands installing library files in the `$INSTALL` directory:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL
$ make -j
$ make install
```

After that, the library files can be found in the `$INSTALL` directory:
headers in `$INSTALL/include` (for example, `$INSTALL/include/foobar.h`)
and library in `$INSTALL/lib` (for example, `$INSTALL/lib/foobar.a`)

The question is how to use cmake to describe a third-party library so that it can be easily used in the project in the future.

I tried to use `add_custom_target`, but I couldn't get a working build (for example, `target_include_directories` does not work with custom target).

Comment: My vote would be to ditch the pure cmake approach and get a package manager involved.

Comment: @sweenish Are you talking about `apt`, `dnf`, `pacman`, etc.? If yes, then not everywhere there is an opportunity to use a package manager.

Comment: I'm talking about conan or vcpkg.

Comment: @sweenish Alas, it is not possible to use conan or vcpkg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drive the build and install of the non-CMake project using CMake, use the [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) module. Ex.

```
ExternalProject_Add(foobar
  SOURCE_DIR # TODO
  INSTALL_DIR "${INSTALL}"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND configure "--prefix=${INSTALL}"
  BUILD_COMMAND make -j
  INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)
```

As for using the targets built by the non-CMake buildsystem, you can tell the CMake-generated buildsystem about them by defining IMPORTED libraries with [`add_library(<name> <type> IMPORTED [GLOBAL])`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries), and then calling the appropriate commands. See the docs for useful info. Ex.

```
add_library(foobar STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_properties(foobar PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${INSTALL}/lib/foobar${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}"
)
target_include_directories(foobar INTERFACE "${INSTALL}/include")
```

and then just [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to the IMPORTED target.

You could also as an alternative, look at using a non-system package manager, such as Conan ([CMake support docs](https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html#conan-tools-cmake)), or vcpkg ([CMake support docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Alas, it is not possible to use conan or vcpkg.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov you mean it's not possible for you in your particular scenario? There's a big difference between that and it not being possible for anyone else in any other given scenario.

Comment: the libraries I would like to use are missing in conan and vcpkg. And adding cmake to the library, preparing conan or vcpkg requires a lot of time and also knowledge of how to do it.